# Using .each() to populate array but first value shows empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a select from where i'm looping all the values and texts into an array.

What I don't understand is why the first value of this array is empty?

```js
var op = new Array();

$('select option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val() !== null) {
    op[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
  }
});

console.log(op);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">select 1</option>
  <option value="1">select 2</option>
  <option value="2">select 3</option>
  <option value="3">select 4</option>
  <option value="4">select 5</option>
</select>
```

> (5) [empty, "Option 1", "option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
>
> 1: "Option 1"
>
> 2: "Option 2"
>
> 3: "Option 3"
>
> 4: "Option 4"

That's what I get from console.

While I do think the code is right I just don't understand why the first value would be empty.

Comment: it's empty because you never assigned anything to op[0]

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, but your values start at 1.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought I had added ' along with the var. using `op["'"+$(this).val()+"'"]` actually avoids this, forgot I was actually using numbers as values.

Comment: If you do that, you won't see the values at all. When you use `console.log()` on an array, you only see the numeric properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the option value as the array index. Since there's no option with `value="0"` you don't have any value in that element of the array.

Instead of using the value as the index, you can just push into the array.

```
    $('select option').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val() !== null) {
            op.push($(this).text());
        }
    });
```

Then there won't be an empty element at the beginning, but the indexes won't correspond to values.

Or you could make `op` an object rather than an array. Then it will only have the properties that you add.

Comment: I actually was thinking of using objects as I need to do nested data. Could you guide me into objects to create something like: op['id'] = {['value1','value2'],['value1','value2']}

Comment: That's not a valid object. Objects are in the form `{key: value, key: value}`

Comment: Just change the initial value: `var op = {}`.

Comment: ok, would something like `{key: {key : value, key : value},key: {key : value, key : value}, key : value}` work?